Performance Comparison Between Tabulation and Memoization for Dynamic Programming
I'm delving into dynamic programming and trying to understand the general performance differences between tabulation and memoization. Both techniques aim to optimize recursive algorithms by storing intermediate results to avoid redundant calculations, but I'm curious about their overall performance.
my questions are:
Which technique generally performs better in practice, considering factors beyond just time complexity?
How do tabulation and memoization compare in terms of memory usage? Are there any typical scenarios where one significantly outperforms the other?

What’s your definition of memoization? Tabulation is just a way to perform structured memoization, after all.

This will be much dependent on the problem. Why not measure the difference in running time yourself?

using object or keymap to store the smaller problems to reuse them .

@trincot for me both works well. i am curious to find which method wins generally?

@nneonneo  there's one more dp approach matrix exponentiation , i think it wins for larger problems .

Each problem has its specific details that may influence the decision. This question seems to broad to me. There is no general case.

Assuming you're considering this terminology:

Tabulation = bottom up or iterative DP
Memoization = top down or recursive DP

Pros of bottom-up DP:

There is no overhead of the recursion call stack. So it tends to have better runtime performance in general (exceptions always apply, see below).
In some cases you can achieve a lower space complexity. For example, in the edit distance problem, if you do it top-down you would need O(mn) space if you do it recursively, but if you do it bottom-up you can populate the table one row at a time which brings the space complexity down to O(min(m, n)) (please see wikipedia for details).

Pros of top-down DP:

Recursive code is very elegant and easy to read. If I don't have to worry a lot about performance and just want to bring the time complexity from exponential to polynomial, I usually go with top-down for this reason alone.
For problems that don't need an exhaustive systematic computation of the entire problem space, top-down DP might be more performant in theory. To give you an example, consider this problem:

"Given an mxn grid with Os and Xs where Os are empty and Xs are blocked, find the shortest path from the top-left cell to the bottom-right cell, if you can only move right and down."
Now imagine the grid looks like this
S O O O O
X X X X O
O O O X O
O O O X O
O O O X E

where S represents start and E represents end. It is immediately apparent that there is just one path from the start to the end.
If you solve this bottom up, you will end up finding the result to every cell in the grid (from the bottom row to the top row) before you find the answer for start cell. But the 3x3 island of Os at the bottom left is completely irrelevant to this problem because all those cells are completely blocked from the start and end cells.
If you do it top down with recursion, it will just consider the only available path: f(0,0) -> f(0, 1) -> f(0, 2) -> f(0, 3) -> f(0, 4) -> f(1, 4) -> f(2, 4) -> f(3, 4) -> f(4, 4).

If performance is really important, you would need to profile your algorithm against real world inputs and decide accordingly.
